# Is this really a "bad" question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about how .NET implements memory management and garbage collection:  [Are gen-0, 1 & 2 actually different areas of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344336/are-gen-0-1-2-actually-different-areas-of-memory)

It's been a little down votes and a close requested as "Unclear what you're asking".

I think the question is perfectly clear.

I agree that it's not an area of .NET that us developers should be concidering when we develop as it's an implementation detail and subject to change, but that shouldn't stop one from being curious.

Any opinions?  I'll delete it if it's agreed as 'bad'.

Comment: @CodeCaster It's something that isn't published anywhere, that I could find.  The only reason I wanted to know is curiosity.  I'd seen a presentation on YouTube that implied that they were copied - I wondered if that was the case.

Comment: [tag:meta-effect] in 3..2..1...

Comment: @xenteros At least it'll either get closed, in which case I'll delete it, or not, in which case there's no bother.

Comment: Well, I think that the topic certainly has value as does understanding the nature of performance hits you can get as well as some of the finer points of GC and safe points and the like.  However, as a question the current form seems rather rough and unclear as to what practical area an answer is supposed to cover.  You probably shouldn't just make it broad enough and hope for someone to post a general overview or tutorial article.  As it is, any succinct answer to the actual question seems like it will provide little information and essentially beg more questions.

Comment: @bitnine I thought that _When an object is promoted from a lower generation to a higher one, is it actually copied into a new memory location or is there a table of which generation objects are in?_ was pretty specific.  It can be answered succunctly, in fact, if it were simplified to: _"When an object is promoted from a lower generation to a higher one, is it actually copied into a new memory location?"_ then it could be answered with a _Yes_ or a _No_.

Comment: It seems to be less than circumspect in begging additional questions given that the current form explicitly contains "Also...  why?"  The yes/no holds little value in and of itself, and asking why the GC works the way it does is pretty broad and fuzzy.

Comment: see [Question closed because yes/no answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773)

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

Comment: Hint: [edit] this answer.

Comment: that made me laugh!  Still, _yes_ would have been a perfectly acceptable answer to my question.

Comment: @BanksySan what about "no"?

Comment: @jwenting it would be deeply hurtful.